Hardy inequality
Suppose $B_1$ is the unit ball centered at the origin in $ R^N$ with $N \ge 3$.  Let $ q= 2^* = \frac{2N}{N-2}$.    Does there exist some $C>0$ such that
$$\int_{B_1} \frac{ u(x)^2}{|x|^2} dx \le C \| u \|_{L^q(B_1)}^2,$$ for all smooth compactly supported (in $B_1$) radial functions?  I assume the answer is false but a counter example maybe isn't completely trivial since both sides scale the same (or maybe it is trivial).  If it holds then is $C$ known?
I tried the obvious thing with Hölder's inequality but of course you just miss;  maybe one can use weak $L^p$ spaces?
any comments greatly appreciated.

The function $u(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{(N/2)-1} |\log |x||^{1/2}}$ is a counterexample in the ball of radius $1/2$

Thank you very much for the counter example.

You can estimate
$\||x|^{-1}u\|_{L^2}\le C
  \||x|^{-1}\|_{L^{n,\infty}} \|u\|_{L^{q,2}}$
in terms of the Lorentz norm $L^{q,2}$ with $q=\frac{2n}{n-2}$. This is slightly stronger than $L^q$, but not too much. This works also on the ball (or any domain).

Thank you very much for your answer.  Are you able to control this norm on the right by the Dirichlet energy also or ?  Also,  i am trying  to ''accept'' your answer but i seem to have forgotten how (eventually i will figure it out).

Now i remember how..thanks.

Of course, the $L^{q,2}$ norm is controlled by the $L^2$ norm of $\partial u$. This is a Sobolev embedding with values in Lorentz spaces

Okay, thanks again.  I am not familiar at all with these other spaces.
